# Heroku NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ADMIN_ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm making a simple blog to learn rails.

Everything is almost finished, and I'm trying to apply HTTP authentication, as outlined here --> http://berk.es/2011/03/29/simplest-authentication-in-rails-basic-authentication-with-a-logged_in-helper/

My authentication code looks like this, in the ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  protected
    def authenticate
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
        username == ADMIN_ID && password == ADMIN_PASSWORD
      end
    end
end
```

instead of passing the variable in my files, however, I want to pass it through heroku. So I ran -->

```
heroku config:add ADMIN_ID=myusername
heroku config:add ADMIN_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

When I tried logging in though I get a "Something went wrong" message. Here's what heroku logs say :

```
GET fast-chamber-1998.herokuapp.com/admin dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin" for 60.245.65.132 at 2012-11-11 07:18:47 +0000
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#admin as HTML
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ADMIN_ID):
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `block in authenticate'
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `authenticate'
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-11T07:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

From the looks of it, I think the environment variables I passed don't seem to be detected. What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access them as `ENV['ADMIN_ID']` and `ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD']`